# Do smart sensor posture trainer help people to effectively improve their posture?

Tags: medical-science

The [LUMOback: The Smart Posture Sensor](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/lumoback/lumoback-the-smart-posture-sensor) gets sold on Kickstarter as a product that's supposed to help people develop better posture and thus reduce backpain.  Is there any research that indicates that posture trainers like this help people to have a better posture and thus less backpain?

Comment: The mode of operation is plausible, but I don't expect there to be any independent studies of a product that, as I understand it, doesn't even exist yet other than some prototypes.